# How to set Principal Class for a loadable bundle?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbundle

OK, I have studied some resources and example code (like [this](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/more_cocoa_examples/082-PlugIns.pl)) and it should be really simple but I still can't find the answer.

I've managed to get the whole thing *(of getting an external bundle to load and integrate)* working, except for one little detail.

I'm get the "main" class from the bundle, using :

```
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle" 
                                                       ofType:@"plugin"];
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
Class someClass = [myBundle principalClass];
```

The thing is : **How** (and where) can I set the "principalClass" in the bundle?

Comment: That is a plist file and it contains key-valued pairs

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That would be the most obvious choice. However, even after setting `NSPrincipalClass="MyClassName"` in my bundle's `info.plist`, it still fails to show up. (or to be precise, it still reports as main class, the one I initially created and then deleted... weird?)

Comment: Amazing and I never tried to do this. And there is not a single bit of help on net, I think no one tried this before you, if anyone had he did not post anywere. i hope you will find the answer and post the solution :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It's part of my attempts of extending my cocoa application with custom-tailored plugins. One way is via ObjC-bridged Python scripts, and the other one (the more UI-dependent) via loadable bundles. Not the most common thing, I suspect...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I've finally managed to fix it. Setting `NSPrincipalClass` **was** indeed fine. However, all my issues stemmed from endless weird Xcode bugs, related to the Plugin Bundle project (needed to clean, re-clean, move existing classes to trash, re-add the classes, make sure `Cocoa.framework` *was* linked, etc, etc and it worked.... Rather frustrating for something that is indeed fairly simple by its very nature... Pff....)

Comment: So please go on to add the solution and step :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I certainly will (it's almost a second nature of mine, these days, to be posting questions on SO, and then answering them myself... lol) - btw, I've got another one for you if you're ready to get your hands dirty with another interesting problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197586/communication-between-main-application-and-loadable-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the issue is rather simple (if we exclude my own issues related to Xcode bugs not actually updating the changes made to the initial project).

As @AnoopVaidya also pointed out, just open up your `info.plist`, and even if the `NSPrincipalClass` key is not there, set its value to the name of your actual "Principal Class".

Once you *Clean* and Re-*Build*, your bundle's principal class should be properly recognised.

**Documentation :**

> NSBundle finds the principal class in one of two ways. First, it looks
> for the NSPrincipalClass key in the bundle’s information property
> list. If the key is present, it uses the class named by the key’s
> value as the bundle’s principal class. If the key is not present or
> the key specifies a class that does not exist, NSBundle uses the first
> class loaded as the principal class. If the bundle is built with
> Xcode, the order of classes as viewed in the project determines the
> order in which they are loaded.

**Source :**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/CocoaBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001269-BAJCIAHA

Comment: I think this is broken. No matter what i Do, it does not find the principal class key in my info.plist file. It always finds some random one the other way

Comment: In a Swift only project, I had to include the bundle (module) name when specifying the Principal Class name in the Info.plist. i.e. "MyModule.MyPrincipalClass".