# Communication between Main Application and loadable bundle

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbundle

OK, it's rather self-explanatory.

Let's say we've got our cocoa application.
Let's all assume that you've already got some "plugins", packaged as independent loadable bundles.

This is how bundles are currently being loaded (given that the plugin's "principal class" is actually an `NSWindowController` subclass :

```
// Load the bundle
NSString* bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BundlePlugin" 
                                                       ofType:@"bundle"]
NSBundle* b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
NSError* err = nil;
[b loadAndReturnError:&err];
if (!err)
{
     // if everything goes fine, initialise the main controller
     Class mainWindowControllerClass = [b principalClass];
     id mainWindowController = [[mainWindowControllerClass alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PluginWindow"];
}
```

**Now, here's the catch :**

- How do I "publish" some of my main app's objects to the plugin?
- How do I make my plugin "know" about my main app's classes?
- Is it even possible to actually establish some sort of communication between them, so that e.g. the plugin can interact with my main app? And if so, how?

---

**SIDENOTES :**

- Could using *Protocols* eliminate the "unknown selector" errors and the need for extensive use of `performSelector:withObject:`?
- Obviously I can set and get value to-and-from my newly created `mainWindowController` as long as they're defined as properties. But is this the most Cocoa-friendly way?

Comment: Old question.  You still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Flyingdiver I am still looking for a answer for this. My need is, I have a NSObject class inside the bundle as principal class and implemented my own methods. How do I expose those methods to the application?